# how to integrate somebody else's Angular code into my own?

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I'm working on an Angular app using:

```
`<html ng-app="navops"></html>`
```

and we hired a designer how gave me a minified JS script and he is using:

```
angular.bootstrap(element,modules,config);
```

so this create an error:

```
App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '<body>'
```

how can I integrate the two codes??

Answer (score 0):

You are bootstrapping twice, remove the ng-app from the body tag and it will work.  If your code then no longer works make sure you add it as a dependency into the `bootstrap()` command.  Presumably you would just add "myLibs" or something into the `modules` array